Troubleshooting Various System Errors: MTRR Inconsistency, ACPI BIOS Errors, PCI Errors, and More
I'm encountering multiple errors and warnings in my system logs and need assistance troubleshooting them. Here's a summary of the issues:
1. MTRR Inconsistency 2. ACPI BIOS Errors  3. PCI Errors 4. PS/2 Port Disabled Warning 5.Device Mapper Warning 6.EISA Allocation Errors 7.AMD Pstate Warning 8.Network Device Errors 9.ACPI Region Errors 10.UBSAN Errors in Kernel Module 11.Process Execution with Executable Stack Warning
here is the output of sudo dmesg -T --color=always --level=err,warn
https://pastebin.com/AiHHvRmr
other info's that might help to debug the issue
HARDWARE INFO - https://pastebin.com/beyEvQJM
kernel & ubuntu info - Linux {username}-laptop 6.5.0-27-generic #28~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 15 10:51:06 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
after windows crashed unable to flash windows due to some errors shifted to ubuntu but alrwares few acpi errors are shown during startup . also i was on 20.04 few week ago i have activation of network problem so i have tried out bunch of commands ( in the provided log their are some errors related to wifi driver also ) that can be cause ( not sure )
how to fix this errors
